# How to detect a text contains in the table using regexp (scalar subquery produced more than one element)

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, google-analytics

i have a problem with myquery.
So i have a table 1 of traffic shop domain.

```
entrance_page_name       | Visitor
www.milkcotton/home/p    | 10
www.cereal/home/category | 11
musicbox1/home           | 12
harrybel1/home           | 14
```

then i have a another table similiar like this

```
shop_domain         | shop_id  
milkcotton          | 1
cereal              | 2
musicbox1           | 3
harrybel1           | 4
```

From that table i want to know which shop is already registered (available shop_id in database). I've tried with this query but it seems did not works:

```
CASE 
WHEN regexp_contains (entrance_page_name, (SELECT shop_domain FROM `data`)) then true end as 'shop'
```

The result

> "Scalar subquery produced more than one element"

hopefully can solve this problem, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't even need regex here, you can use the base string function `INSTR()`:

```sql
SELECT t.entrance_page_name, t.Visitor
FROM traffic t
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM shop_domain d
    WHERE INSTR(t.entrance_page_name, d.shop_domain) > 0
);
```

Comment: I'm really sorry, I still can't elaborate on this query, I need this query in a part of the 'case when' function. Can you help me? thanks a lot

Comment: You can use `CASE WHEN EXISTS (SELECT 1 ... )` I can't see your full query, hence I cannot say more here.

Comment: it's okay, i got it! thanks a lot!